# Match punctuated characters

Tags: string, compare, ascii, punctuation

I'm looking for a way to compare string values where certain characters within the strings may be punctuated characters such as `é` or `ô`, however, the puncuation should be disregarded. For example, when searching a list of names, the user might provide criteria `Rene` which should match list entries `Rene` and `René` (i.e. ASCII 101 and 233 should be regarded as the same thing).

Thanx

**EDIT:** Preferably across all UNICODE characters. I suppose one could [should?] implement some custom solution for this; I was just wondering if there is something that already exist - almost like `Char.GetBaseCharacterFromPunctuatedCharacter(char)` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say which language you are using so I answer using java. Other languages have similar constructs. Also, you mean diacritics, not [punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) (.,?!...)

The [collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class supports the strength of comparison. For example, for Czech, difference in diacritics is considered to be a secondary difference.

Or you might want to remove any diacritics prior comparison by unicode canonical decomposition (decomposing all characters into basic letters + diacritics) and then removing the diacritics by a simple regex (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697171/regex-what-is-incombiningdiacriticalmarks) for an explanation of `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks`). In java:

```
public static String removeDiacritics(String str) {
  return Normalizer
     .normalize(string, Form.NFD)   // decompose into letters+diacritics
     .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""); // remove diacritics
}
```

Comment: Hehe, so the actual issue here was that I didn't actually know what it was called, so I didn't know what to look for. Normalization works but straight comparison is also possible, both illustrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison

Comment: Yes, the collator I mention above can do straight comparison in java corresponding to the c# code you link to. (If you agree with my answer, could you upvote it?)