# Apache Commons UrlValidator - configure to allow umlaut characters

Tags: java, special-characters, apache-commons, url-validation

I would like to validate a long list of URL strings, but some of them contain umlaut characters, e.g.: ä, à, è, ö, etc.

Is there a way to configure the Apache Commons UrlValidator to accept these characters?

**This test fails (notice the ã):**

```
@Test
public void urlValidatorShouldPassWithUmlaut()
{
    // Given
    org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator validator;
    validator = new UrlValidator( new String[] { "http", "https" }, UrlValidator.ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES );

    // When
    String url = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/São_Paulo";

    // Then
    assertThat( validator.isValid( url ), is( true ) );
}
```

**This test passes (ã replaced with a):**

```
@Test
public void urlValidatorShouldPassWithUmlaut()
{
    // Given
    org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator validator;
    validator = new UrlValidator( new String[] { "http", "https" }, UrlValidator.ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES );

    // When
    String url = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sao_Paulo";

    // Then
    assertThat( validator.isValid( url ), is( true ) );
}
```

Software version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

`validator.isValid( IDN.toASCII(url) )` also fails as `IDN.toASCII(url)` does things that I don't yet understand, e.g. it converts `http://dbpedia.org/resource/São_Paulo` into `http://dbpedia.xn--org/resource/so_paulo-w1b`, which is still invalid according to `UrlValidator`

Comment: Are you using org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator or org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator?

Comment: org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator (org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator is deprecated)

Comment: Have you tried running the validation against `IDN.toASCII(url)`?

Comment: thanks, I just tried but it doesn't work, see comment below

Comment: IDN.toAscii("http://dbpedia.org/resource/São_Paulo") ==
"http://dbpedia.xn--org/resource/so_paulo-w1b" which is still invalid

Comment: @AlexAverbuch use java.net.URLEncoder as my answer below.Your url's umlaut part needs to be encoded to pass validation.

Answer (score 1):

You must encode the umlaut part before you validate it as:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class UmlautUrlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/";
        String umlautPart="São_Paulo";
        UrlValidator v= null;
        try {
            String s[]={"http", "https"};
            v = new UrlValidator(s, UrlValidator.ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES);
            String encodedUrl=URLEncoder.encode(umlautPart,"UTF-8");
            System.out.println(v.isValid(url+encodedUrl));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
true
S%C3%A3o_Paulo
```

**EDIT:**

You can use this function for encoding the whole url for parsing.

```
public static String encodeUrl(String url) {
        String temp[] = url.split("://");
        String protocol = temp[0];
        String restOfUrl = temp[1];
        temp = restOfUrl.split("\\.");
        //for the all except last token of host
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i++) {
            try {
                temp[i] = URLEncoder.encode(temp[i], "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
        String temp2[] = temp[temp.length - 1].split("/");
        String host = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i++) {
            host = host + temp[i];
        }
        try {
            host = host + "." + URLEncoder.encode(temp2[0], "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        host = host.substring(0);
        String remainingPart = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < temp2.length; i++) {
            try {
                remainingPart = remainingPart + "/" + URLEncoder.encode(temp2[i], "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
        return (protocol + "://" + host + remainingPart);
    }
```

And use in your test: `validator.isValid(encodeUrl(url))`

Comment: is there no way to tell ´UrlValidator´ (or an alternative library - I'm open to suggestions) that umlauts are allowed, rather than performing the encoding? the code should only *validate* that a lot of text elements a formatted as expected. transforming the text elements seems unnecessary and inefficient as the transformed text is immediately discarded.

Comment: @AlexAverbuch the way I have given is the standard way to deal with special characters in java URL's. I do not know of any such special libraries.To me I always feel it to be better to stick to the more accepted way of getting things done. And BTW my solution does not transforms,rather it Encodes.

Comment: @AlexAverbuch whatever you are facing is an open issue with apache commons. See this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VALIDATOR-235?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13158329#comment-13158329

Comment: given your solution, what would i do if I didn't know which part of the URL the umlaut is in?

Comment: thanks, I've also edited to fix a bug where it unnecessarily encoded "." characters in the path

Comment: temp = restOfUrl.split("\\."); So "." characeters in hostname are not getting encoded.Where have you edited my code?

Answer (score 0):

While reading this SO question ([Regex: what is InCombiningDiacriticalMarks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697171/regex-what-is-incombiningdiacriticalmarks)) I found that another partial solution is as follows:

```
    public static boolean removeAccentsAndValidateUrl( String url )
    {
        String normalizedUrl = Normalizer.normalize( url, Normalizer.Form.NFD );
        Pattern accentsPattern = Pattern.compile( "\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+" );
        String urlWithoutAccents = accentsPattern.matcher( normalizedUrl ).replaceAll( "" );
        String[] schemes = {"http", "https"};
        long options = UrlValidator.ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES;
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator( schemes, options );
        return urlValidator.isValid(urlWithoutAccents);
    }
```

However, it turns out that UrlValidator also fails on (among others) "-" characters.

For example, the following fails validation:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/PENTA_–_Pena_Transportes_Aereos
```