# onTextChanged custom filter german umlauts

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

Im using a Filter for an `ArrayAdapter`. Now I would like to have following Feature:

For Example my Listview contains the word `käuflich` and the search Input is `kauf`, `käuflich` should be displayed as result. So ö,ä,ü should be replaced additionally by o,a,u.
Is this possible?

This is my simple filter

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        Activity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `java.text.Normalizer` to remove the accents. When iterating over list items in `Filter.performFiltering(CharSequence)`, do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i<Original_Names.size(); i++){
    filterableString = Original_Names.get(i);

    String s = Normalizer.normalize(filterableString, Form.NFD);

    // Remove Accents
    String withoutAccents = 
        s.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");

    if(withoutAccents.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
        Filtered_Names.add(filterableString);
    }
}
```

A word of caution here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697575)

Comment: Thank you, code is implemented but the search is very slow. My Array list is filled from a SQL query, may this is the Problem?

Comment: @Oli Yes, that can be the problem. But sorry, I cannot give you a sure answer. Is the list getting filtered correctly?