# How to Change specified characters in java?

Tags: java

I want to send this character 'çıüğöşİĞÜÖŞÇ' and return this 'ciugosIGUOSC'
For example;
String name ="FATİH DURMUŞ";
      return "FATIH DURMUS"

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222972/removing-accent-marks-diacritics-from-latin-characters-for-comparison

Comment: This question may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/%C5%84-%C7%B9-%C5%88-%C3%B1-%E1%B9%85-%C5%86-%E1%B9%87-%E1%B9%8B-%E1%B9%89-%CC%88-%C9%B2-%C6%9E-%E1%B6%87-%C9%B3-%C8%B5-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha